# Set a color to a String Java

Tags: java, string, file, colors, set

I have this code:

```
public Collection test {

   String valRegistre;
   ...


   boolean a = testRegistre(valRecupReceiveData);

   if(a == true) {
       valRegistre = "Resultat du TEST OK";}
   else {
       valRegistre = "Resultat du TEST MAUVAIS - Message d'erreur affiche : " + valRecupReceiveData;        
   }
   ...
}
```

The String valRegistre is send to a file txt which will be read by a human. I would like to set a color to this String to have a easy way to read the file.

Comment: You can't have colours in a pure text file. So you need to use a different format.

Comment: You can use html and format it as you wish.

Comment: What assylias said. Maybe you could have a class with a color and a String. Maybe write a "prettify" method, that would output the text in HTML for example.

Comment: I guess what you need are tags which needs to be processed by the text editor to deteremine what color needs to be displayed.

Comment: Whenever post on SO please format code first and then post.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The .txt file format has no native support for colour.

I suggest you send your results to a html file that the human will read in a browser.

Using the html format is easier, standardised and possibly more expressive.

Example:

```
<html><body><font color=\"red\">Ton test est mauvais</font></body></html>"
```

Comment: I noticed you went with this answer.  Note that the example is bad: the `font` tag (and thus also its `color` attribute) is not supported in HTML 5.  Use CSS instead.

Answer (score 1):

A `String` object represents the text data only, and as such has no support for colors, fonts or anything that has to do with the ***representation*** of the text.

Additionally, the .txt file format is plain text and has no support for representation aspects either.

If you want control over the representation, you need to use a file format that supports it, like **html** or **pdf** or **rtf**.  **html** will most likely be the easiest one.  To specify the color you will need to use CSS styles, which can be defined inside the same file.

e.g.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <style>
      .error {
        color: red;
      }
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <span class="error">Resultat du TEST MAUVAIS</span>
  </body>
</html>
```